# Calculate an input vector x that satisfies a known output vector of matrix transformation T(x)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, transformation

I have been struggling to figure out this matrix transformation question that asks me to describe a vector **x** that satisfies:

$$
T(x) = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    -8 \\
    9 \\
    2 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

I am given a matrix:

$$
A = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 3 & 1 \\
    -2 & 1 & 5\\
    0 & 2 & 2\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

I am also aware that T(**x**) = A**x**. I would like to know the general process for finding what **x** is when given the output vector and a matrix to be multiplied by the unknown input vector **x**.

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & -2 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

I have tried putting the augmented matrix in reduced row echelon form above, but I am not sure where to go from there. Any tips are very much appreciated.

Comment: "I have tried putting the augmented matrix in reduced row echelon form, but I am not sure where to go from there." And what does that look like?

Comment: @Arthur It doesn't seem like I can use mathjax formatting in replies, but here is the rref matrix anyway: row 1: 1 0 -2 0, row 2: 0 1 1 0, row 3: 0 0 0 1. Since the last row claims 0=1, it seems like this matrix is inconsistent

Comment: You can definitely use mathjax in comments. There just isn't a preview, so you won't see the result beforehand:$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}dx = \sqrt\pi$$That being said, I would rather you put that into the original post.

Comment: @Arthur Edited, thanks for the suggestion!